# How to connect memcached laravel and docker?

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, memcached

I have created the memcached container in docker
docker-compose.yml:

```
#store cache
  memcached:
    image: memcached
    container_name: memcached
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
```

.env

```
MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached
MEMCACHED_PORT=11211
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
```

and in my `config/cache.php` file section `stores` as follows:

```
 'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

In a method I have made the following example:

```
  $user = \Cache::remember('user', 60, function() {
                 return \App\Models\User::first();
             }); */
             $c = new \Memcached();
             $c->addServer("memcached", 11211);
             var_dump( $c->getAllKeys() );
```

but I am getting the error:

```
Error: Class 'Memcached' not found
```

I don't know if it is a problem in my container, since when I enter the container with this command:

```
docker-compose exec --user 0 memcached bash
```

I run the stats command inside the container but I get the error that it has not been found

```
root@520aaa151216:/# stats
bash: stats: command not found
```

I have executed:

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

however the memcached errors continue.

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
LABEL version="1.0"

#install pdftk
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    locales \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    curl \
    npm \
    supervisor \
    pdftk

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql bcmath mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.0.4 \ && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory contents
WORKDIR /var/www
ADD ./ /var/www

# install laravel
RUN COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install

RUN composer dump-autoload
RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan route:cache
RUN php artisan route:clear

#npm install
#USER root

RUN npm i npm@latest -g
RUN npm install --global yarn

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Copy supervisor configuration
ADD docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf

#Expose ports
EXPOSE 9000
EXPOSE 9003
#Run commands
CMD  ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile ?

Comment: @gguney I have edited my question, already with the dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Found in this link: https://github.com/devilbox/docker-php-fpm/blob/master/Dockerfiles/mods/Dockerfile-7.3

I have added in my dockerfile:

```
# Install Memcached for php 7
RUN set -eux \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
    && true
```